# Wordpress http, https redirect. случайно изменил в настройках http на https и теперь не заходит на сайт

Tags: wordpress, http, https, redirect, http-redirect

Я использовал бесплатный хостинг, поэтому сайт был на http, в админ панели WP решил изменить с http на https. И теперь вылезает это "Этот сайт не может обеспечить безопасное соединение", при попытке ввести http он перенаправляет на https.

Могли бы вы пожалуйста подсказать где находиться файл отвечающий за редирект, и сказать какой участок кода поправить чтобы сайт снова перешёл на http

Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Всё, Нашёл ответ благодаря документации

> Нужно вставить в wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

вместо example.com вставляете ссылку на главную страницу сайта